# Como acessar um array dentro de um metodo em uma classe?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como faço para acessar um array por meio de um método. Gostaria de saber  que vocês acham do meu código esta certo o que estou tentando fazer?

```
class RegisterPostType
{   
    public $name;
    public $singleName;
    public $addNew;
    public $addNewItem;
    public $editNewItem;
    public $newItem;
    public $viewItem;
    public $searchItem;
    public $notFound;
    public $notFoundinTrash;

    private function labels()
    {
        $label = array(
            'name'                  =>     $this->name,
            'singular_name'         =>     $this->singleName,
            'add_new'               =>     $this->addNew,
            'add_new_item'          =>     $this->addNewItem,
            'edit_item'             =>     $this->editNewItem,
            'new_item'              =>     $this->newItem,
            'view_item'             =>     $this->viewItem,
            'search_items'          =>     $this->searchItem,
            'not_found'             =>     $this->notFound,
            'not_found_in_trash'    =>     $this->notFoundinTrash,
            'parent_item_colon'     =>     ''
        );
    }

    public function registerPostType()
    {
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $this->labels()->label,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => null,
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
        ); 
    }
}
```

E estou chamando o array dessa maneira:

```
add_action('init', 'postTypes');
function postTypes()
{
    $header = new RegisterPostType;
    $header->name = 'Titulo';
    $header->singleName = 'Titulo';
    $header->addNew = 'Titulo';
    $header->addNewItem = 'Titulo';
    $header->editNewItem = 'Titulo';
    $header->newItem = 'Titulo';
    $header->viewItem = 'Titulo';
    $header->searchItem = 'Titulo';
    $header->notFound = 'Titulo';
    $header->notFoundinTrash = 'Titulo';
    register_post_type('header', $header->registerPostType()->args);
}
```

Aproveitei e dei um var_dump no ARRAY e ele esta me retornando NULL. Poderia me ajuda?

Comment: Como `$label` é uma variavel privada do método(privado) `labels()` você precisa dar um `return` pois é a unica forma de recuperar esse array.

Comment: O código não parece fazer nenhum sentido. Criar métodos que criam variáveis locais e não fazem mais nada não tem nenhuma utilidade. Por isto não entendi a dúvida. Tente informar seu objetivo porque o código não demonstra intenção de fazer nada útil. Você quer fazer alguma coisa com estas variáveis? O que? Passar o conteúdo destas variáveis para outro lugar? Na verdade o código parece fazer muita coisa sem necessidade. Pode ser uma impressão errada mas você pode esclarecer o objetivo de todas estas funções.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o objetivo é um método para formatar o um array, não esquece dar um `return` na variável desejada, um método/função sem return, retorna null, que no php é interpretado como false.

Variáveis criadas dentro de métodos não são atributos da classe logo perdem o seu valor após a execução do método, caso precise desses valores mais adiante uma opção é internaliza-la como membro da classe.

```
private function labels()
{
  return array('name' => $this->name ...)
}
```

chamada:

```
public function registerPostType()
{
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $this->labels() //agora sim o método retorna algo.
```